# How to make code run every X seconds in C programming language

Tags: c

I am trying to make a code run repeatedly every X seconds.

Let me paint a wrestling scenario.

I have already written a code line to give Tyson fury a 5Kg punch at 40 seconds into the fight and then stop.. but there's no way I'm going to win the match with just one 5kg punch at 40 seconds. I need to be able to keep punching every 40 seconds.

Please who knows how I can achieve this?

PS.

```c
{
    real punch;
    real time = CURRENT_TIME;
    real tau = 40; 
    if (time<=tau) 
    {
        punch=5;
    }
    else  
    {
        punch=0;
    }
    return punch;
}
```

Comment: Please show the code as a [mre]. At the simplest level you can just have a loop that does `sleep(40); punch();`. But without seeing your code it's unknown whether that is appropriate. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please do not post code as an image - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question. Please ensure it is complete code. Repeat, please read: [mre].

Comment: Please read [mre]. What you have given is not complete code. Complete code means code that anyone can take exactly as shown to reproduce your scenario.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run something every t seconds in C?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2049870/90527)

Answer (score 0):

In a scenario where time acquisition is possible, as I can see you use

> CURRENT_TIME

You can do it like this:

```
static int lastTimeExecuted = 0; // Using int here, but you should mach type of CURRENT_TIME 

// See how much time passed since last execution
if ((CURRENT_TIME - lastTimeExecuted) >= 40) 
{
    punch  = 5;
    lastTimeExecuted = CURRENT_TIME ;
}
else
{
    punch = 0;
}
```

Just remember that code abowe shuld be in a loop.